# check month in quarter sql

Tags: sql, db2

How to check where particular month is in particular quarter of an year in sql db2.
like months 1-4 in quarter 1 like than i want to check whether month-1 is in which quarter of the year

Comment: `Extract(month from column)` is ANSI SQL. Or perhaps you should do `MONTH(column)`.

Comment: yeah i am able to get month from date but i have to check that in which quarter that month belongs to..

Comment: `case when monthval in (1,2,3) then 'q1' when monthval in (4,5,6) then 'q2' ... end`

Comment: give an example for what the input is and what the expected output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
SELECT
    MyDate,
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 1) + 'Q3'
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 1) + 'Q4'
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 0) + 'Q1'
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 0) + 'Q2'
    END AS Quarter
FROM
    MyTable
order by Quarter
```

OR

```
SELECT
   date
   , CASE
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'First Quarter'
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Second Quarter'
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Third Quarter'
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Fourth Quarter'
     END AS quarter
FROM Stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

DB2 has a built-in [`QUARTER` function](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000837.html?pos=2) that does what I think you want:

```
SELECT QUARTER(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```